# What is the statistical test to distinguish whether a double mutant shows synergism (=positive epistasis) between the single mutants?

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have been analyzing aberrant phenotypes in different genotypes.
Mutation *a* displays the aberrant phenotype in 19 of 273 individuals, that is: 19 aberrant (r), and 254 are normal (n).
Mutation *b* displays the phenotype in 11 of 254 individuals, that is: 11 are (r), 244 are (n).
The double mutation *a,b* shows the phenotype in 81 of 443 individuals, that is: 81 are (r), and 362 are (n).
What statistical test would be in order to test for synergism between mutations a and b?

I would suggest a Chi square test, using:

*a+b*: 497 (n) 30 (r) (creating a virtual category by adding the frequencies of both single mutants, anticipating an additive effect)

*a,b*: 362 (n) 81 (r) (the double mutant)

resulting in: chi-square statistic is 37.6571. The p-value is < .00001. The result is significant at p < .01.

Is this a valid approach?

Thank you very much in advance for any insights and help in this matter.

Comment: Please remember that not all readers here will be familiar with genetics. Defining your terms will increase the likelihood of your getting a good answer.

Comment: @Schwantke The commenting section is not the place to pursue grievances about how the site works, which is why people have flagged your comment and I have deleted it.  Please confine such discussion to our Meta site.

Answer (score 5):

What you seem to be doing is comparing two proportions 30:497 and 81:362 in a 2x2 table

```r
30  497
81  362
```

This can be done by different tests. The chi-squared test and the z-test are possibilities (and they are actually equivalent, you can transform the z-score into the chi-squared value and vice versa).

However, this is not showing synergy! Synergy would be like : the two mutations combined would be an effect that is greater than the sum of the single effects. E.g. 81/443 > 19/273 + 11/254.

To test the significance of the synergetic effect you could set up a linear model with an interaction term that represents the synergy, and perform some glm regression with a binomial family as model for the residuals.

---

In R you could do it like the following:

```r
# data:
y <- cbind(n = c(254, 244, 362), 
           r = c(19, 11, 81))
xa <- c(1,0,1)
xb <- c(0,1,1)

# model without synergism 
#
# That is: simply combination of two effects
#          probability of normal with a and b together is prodoct of 
#          probability of normal with a,b seperate
#          q_ab = q_a * q_b
#          
#          possibly you wish to define it differently
#
mod1 <- glm(y ~ 0 + xa + xb , family=binomial(link="log"))  
     # note: log link makes the addition in the linear model multiplicative

# model with synergism
#
# This has an interaction term xa*xb added
# , which expresses the difference relative to simple addition 
#   when both a,b occur 
mod2 <- glm(y ~ 0 + xa + xb + xa*xb , family=binomial(link="log"))
```

Which results in p-values around 0.005/0.007 (it is a bit dependent on the method, the values are not exact but approximations)

```r
> # likelihood ratio test 
> anova(mod1, mod2, test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: y ~ 0 + xa + xb
Model 2: y ~ 0 + xa + xb + xa * xb
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)   
1         1     7.1859                        
2         0     0.0000  1   7.1859 0.007348 **
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
> # z-test
> summary(mod2)$coefficients
         Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
xa    -0.07213753 0.01655307 -4.357954 0.0000131284
xb    -0.04409532 0.01329632 -3.316356 0.0009119954
xa:xb -0.08569271 0.03091748 -2.771659 0.0055771502
> 
> # probabilities for r phenotype
> 1-mod1$fitted.values
         1          2          3 
0.09833522 0.06277834 0.15494024 
> 1-mod2$fitted.values
         1          2          3 
0.06959707 0.04313725 0.18284424 
> 
> # note that this is te exponent of the coefficients in the linear model
> # because we used the log link function
> 1-exp(coefficients(mod1))
        xa         xb 
0.09833522 0.06277834
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and competent help, I am grateful.